# When to shown app intro onboarding? before or after sign up

Tags: ios, mobile-application, onboarding, android

For mobile applications when it is good to show the app intro onboarding(slider with app features). I have seen some mobile apps showing app intro before signup process and most after. Which is most effective?

According to my view, if a user install app directly after browsing app store, its better to have upfront app intro, since user may not have read the details about the app (installed at the first glance). For user who read about app somewhere and installed it is better to have app intro afterwards, since user already know good deal about the app. But that's my view, it's not users. Most of the time, I skip the app intros, since I just want to get to the main screen of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a walk-through or is it an onboarding ? You mention it is an walk-through but it sounds more of an onboarding.

If it is an onboarding ( Feature presentation ) I would place it when the app opens for the first time.
If it is walkthrough ( Explaining functionality ) I would place it after sign-up.

Onboarding is what encourages a user to sign up to the app so if you are making an onoarding show it when the app opens. Yes, some power users will skip it, that`s why most of onboarding allows users to skip it either by using a Skip option or showing a Sign-up option

Comment: sorry bad terminology, edited, it's an on-boarding. By explaining functionality mean how to do particular thing?

Comment: Yes.A walkthrough would be to present the buttons, where to get started, how to access messages and such where onboarding is more on the side of telling the user that your app allows messages and has buttons.

Comment: thanks for the answer but you did not mention any reasoning behind your decision? adding reasoning would be great

Comment: Sorry, I had it clear in my head :)). Onboarding is what encourages a user to sign up to the app so if you are making an onoarding show it when the app opens. 

Yes, some power users will skip it, that`s why most of onboarding allows users to skip it either by using a Skip option or showing a Sign-up option.

Comment: @please add it the reasoning to the answer so it looks complete

Comment: I'm...not sure i agree with your definition of "onboarding". Onboarding is effectively a high-level tutorial: it's meant to get new users used to some basic actions they can take to get started. It's a form of training, not a marketing ploy.